# Jacobi Conjecture in characteristic $p$, results of Pekka Nousiainen

Tags: reference-request, polynomials

Pekka Nousiainen proved in his PhD thesis "On the Jacobian problem in positive characteristic" at Pennsylvania State University, 1981, a version of the Jacobian Conjecture mod $p$. The results were never published. Does anyone have a copy of this thesis available?

Comment: Do you have access to ProQuest.com?

Comment: No, never heard of it.

Comment: I checked. It's not on ProQuest.